# Calculating Image Size for textView for different screen sizes

Tags: android, textview, screen

Guys I have searched a lot on Stackoverflow, Developers guide for android and on other websites But, Nothing could make me understand how to solve my issue. So, Please help me I am stuck on it from around 10 days.

My query is that if I have to place images in 5 adjacent TextViews. Then how can I calculate their sizes so that they will fit on all devices with different screen sizes and densities. I want Something like this.

[image: First three lines are regular TextViews and I have no problems with that my main concern is in fourth line where I have 3 round images, 1 square image, and 1 rectangular image of big width.]

First three lines are regular TextViews and I have no problems with that my main concern is in fourth line where I have 3 round images, 1 square image, and 1 rectangular image of big width.

I also tried 9 patch images they also doesn't seem to be fit in my case. So, please guide me How to calculate size for ldpi, xhdpi, mdpi, hdpi screens. Also, Please note that I do not have sufficient  devices to check on all I can do is to Give a check on emulators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`please guide me How to calculate size for ldpi, xhdpi, mdpi, hdpi screens`.

mdpi (160 dpi) is the unity (1.0x).

ldpi (120 dpi) is **0.75x**.
hdpi (240 dpi) is **1.5x**.
xhdpi (320 dpi) is **2.0x**.
xxhdpi (480 dpi) is **3.0x**.
xxxhdpi (640 dpi) is **4.0x**.

So, for instance, a 100px by 50px in mdpi would be 200px by 100px in xhdpi.

Comment: I know these scaling guidelines. but my question is how to find this 100px and 50px (from your example).

Comment: You decide it. You decide the size of the unit scale (mdpi res) images. Then basing on it, you calculate all the others. Or were you asking which are the standard icon sizes, instead?

Comment: No, I am not asking for standard image size. just look at my image I want to know how to calculate the size for each image rightly for any one version(hdpi for ex as I have hdpi device)

Comment: So, reread my words. **You decide** the size you think is acceptable at mdpi resolution. Then use the scaling factors I provided to calculate the sizes for all the other resolutions. **It can't be easier** than this.

Comment: Thanks, I got the idea.